# Annotating nested structures/values in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

Say I have a JSON object with some properties in a nested object.

```
{
    "title": "My Blog Post",
    "meta": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way I can just add a `@context` to my top-level object to reach
these properties (i.e. just "pass through" the meta object)? Something along
these lines:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "title": "schema:name",
        "meta.publishedAt": {
            "@type": "xsd:date",
            "@id": "schema:datePublished"
        }
    },

    "@id": "/my-article",
    "title": "My Blog Post",

    "meta": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid having to add (duplicate) `@id` to the nested object, which is how I would otherwise have solved it:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "title": "schema:name",
        "meta": { "@id": "_:meta", "@container": "@set" },
        "publishedAt": {
            "@type": "xsd:date",
            "@id": "schema:datePublished"
        }
    },

    "@id": "/my-article",
    "title": "My Blog Post",

    "meta": {
        "@id": "/my-article",
        "publishedAt": "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

This solution *works*, but requires duplication, and comes from [ethanresnick's
comments on Github](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/587#issuecomment-103367380) about annotating JSON API. He noted in [another issue](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/98#issuecomment-137917064) that `@context` is not "quite expressive enough to annotate the JSON API structure". I was hoping to prove him wrong at least with regards to this issue.

Comment: If you simply defined the `publishedAt` term it will work for all instances (but, you probably want `xsd:dateTime`, not `xsd:date`).

Comment: If what you're trying to do is eat the `meta` element, then no, this can't be done in JSON-LD.

Comment: @GreggKellogg Thanks! You're right about `xsd:dateTime` of course. I'm sad to hear that. If you post your comment as an answer I would mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just discovered that the latest JSON-LD spec includes a new section on [nested properties](http://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#nested-properties). Defining your context like this should result in the desired output:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "title": "schema:name",
        "meta": "@nest",
        "publishedAt": {
            "@type": "xsd:date",
            "@id": "schema:datePublished",
            "@nest": "meta"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fantastic news! Reading the spec, don't you have to include `"meta": "@nest"` in `@context`?

Answer (score 3):

If what you're trying to do is eat the meta element, then no, this can't be done in JSON-LD.

There have been discussions about doing an inverse-index that could do something like this, but I don't see an issue.  You might create one at https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/issues. At some point the CG, or a newly formed WG will start looking at feature requests for a new version.